# Font-Awesome icon won't change onclick

Tags: jquery, font-awesome, toggleclass

This is so simple, but I can't get it to work! On clicking a button, I'd like to change the icon in that button from fa-download to fa-spinner, but the fa-spinner just won't show up!

My HTML is:

```
<button id='save'><i class='fa fa-download' aria-hidden='true'></i> save work</button>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$('body').on('click', '#save', function(e){
   $('#save').find('i').toggleClass('fa-download fa-spinner');
   $("#save").text("loading...");
});
```

The text changes to loading, the download icon goes away, but the spinner icon never shows up! What am I missing?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the .text() function is removing your **i** element.

Maybe put the "save work" text in a span and target that to change its text to "loading..."?

Comment: Ah!! I think you're right! Let me try that. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: :) Glad that helps! JSFiddle above.

Comment: Beautiful! Totally fixed. Was staring at it too long to realize :) Thanks! Will mark as answer when S.O. lets me.

Comment: Awesome, I know that feeling - just need a rubber duck to talk to! ;) 

[See Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

You can either `toggleClass()` or use `addClass()` or `removeClass()`

```
$('body').on('click', '#save', function(e){
   $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-download');
   $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-spinner');
});
```

Comment: This will work, just as his code would be working. The issue is that the .text() function is removing the font-awesome element.