# Change Font Awesome Icon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to change the class of a font awesome icon so that it changes icon when clicked. I have read several other questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147392/font-awesome-icon-wont-change-onclick) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266545/how-to-toggle-font-awesome-icon-on-click)) but have been unsuccessful in getting a working example.

In this case I am trying to change the facebook icon to a tick.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./java.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="javascript:void" rel="me"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
      <a id="facebookicon" href="javascript:void" rel="me"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#facebookicon').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-facebook-square fa-check-square')
});
```

I have also tried this Javascript code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#facebookicon', function(){
   $('i').toggleClass('fa-facebook-square fa-check-square');
});
```

When I click of the icon I get a syntax error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script
```

I think this relates to the `javascript:void` but i'm not sure. When I tried to fix this the answers all seem to be people having quotation marks in the wrong place or mixing and matching double and single quotes. I don't think that it is the case here.

I see many people aiming to have the toggle effect but ultimately I would like it such that it changes once and will NOT change back if clicked again.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: did you try `javascript:;` or `javascript:void(0)` ?

Comment: @Jai and @Manoz The use of `javascript:void(0)` does solve the syntax error I was having but when I copy and paste your code I do not get the icons changing locally in Firefox 50.1. @Jai your answer does seem to do so here but I am unable to reproduce it locally and even so it changes back if i click it twice.

Comment: This should work as @Jai mentioned in his answer. The only suspect is how do you render `#facebookicon` in your DOM. Does this exist or you load it dynamically?

Comment: @Lee Han Kyeol Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/g_thomson/05zb3L6m/13/

Comment: @Manoz I am new to this. What is the difference? I don't think it is dynamically. `#facebookicon` is a font icon from the font awesome package.

Comment: @Jai  Could you take a look at my JSfiddle as it doesn't work there either

Comment: @G_T, works there - https://jsfiddle.net/05zb3L6m/14/
you forgot to include jquery.

Comment: @Manoz I see. But for some reason it still doesn't run locally where I am loading jquery.

Comment: @G_T, Can you paste your whole html here - https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Manoz I have done so here https://pastebin.com/jgnr0tyV

Comment: @G_T, Seems everything is correct in your html. I am not sure if your path to `java.js` is correct ? That might be culprit, No?

Comment: @Manoz it is the first javascript clip in the question and also the JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `javascript:void(0)` in the href attribute of your anchor and as i mentioned in the comment you can use your first snippet if your anchor elements are not created dynamically:

```js
$('#facebookicon').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-facebook-square fa-check-square')
});
```

```css
  a {color: magenta;
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="me"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
  <a id="facebookicon" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="me"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: see my comment above

Comment: @G_T That is strange but here it is not easy to say what is going on. can you confirm you don't get any error in the console while doing that?

Comment: When I copy the code in the div tags of your answer into the body of the HTML of my question I can confirm I don't get any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Change `javascript:void` to `javascript:void(0)` or `javascript:;`

Here is an example 
https://jsfiddle.net/54wkxk4y/

Comment: See my comment above